# URL parameter in Django RESTApi

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rest

Thank you in advance,
I'm new to Django REST Framework.
when i use get() method with id parameter, it is working fine

Below is url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'api/userList/$', UserList.as_view(), name="userList"),
url(r'^api/userList/(?P<id>\d+)/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name="userDetails")
]
```

Below is api.py:

```
class UserDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        model = Users.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = UsersSerializers(model)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**above code is fine**

When i try to get user details by using emailID, i'm not able to get the details, showing below error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    1. admin/
    2. api/userList/$ [name='userList']
    3. ^api/userList/(?P<emailID>\d+)/$ [name='userDetails']
The current path, api/userList/sannila1527@gmail.com/, didn't match any of these.
```

Below is api.py:

```
class UserDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request, emailID):
        model = Users.objects.get(emailID=emailID)
        serializer = UsersSerializers(model)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url.py to

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'api/userList/$', UserList.as_view(), name="userList"),
url(r'^api/userList/(?P<emailID>\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name="userDetails")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this, **urls.py**

```
url(r'^api/userList/(?P<id>\d+)/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name="userDetails")
```

to,

```
url(r'^api/userList/(?P<emailID>\d+)/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name="userDetails")
```

> Note: This can make problems at other places, you can fix them by replacing `id` with `emailID` elsewhere.